# Cython: unusual assert False in get_type_information_cname with template syntax error

Tags: python, list, segmentation-fault, cython

I have since figured out the correct syntax to avoid this, but I would like some input on what's causing this. I am a beginner at Cython.

Due to grossly misunderstanding the typing module, I tried to get a .pyx to accept a data type

```
list[string] var_name = ["string1", "string2"]
```

without realizing this is not correct syntax. To get out of this myself, I stopped trying to explicitly type my vars and just left them dynamically typed. But what was a bit interesting is what happens when you try to keep going with this.

When compiling the .pyx with Cython (version 0.29.14) using

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

however, it throws this instead of any kind of syntax error (which, in older versions of Cython, returns a segmentation fault instead):

```
[1/1] Cythonizing example.pyx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 12, in <module>
    setup(ext_modules = cythonize(ext, language_level = "3"))
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1096, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1202, in cythonize_one
    result = compile_single(pyx_file, options, full_module_name=full_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 727, in compile_single
    return run_pipeline(source, options, full_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py", line 515, in run_pipeline
    err, enddata = Pipeline.run_pipeline(pipeline, source)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py", line 355, in run_pipeline
    data = run(phase, data)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py", line 335, in run
    return phase(data)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Pipeline.py", line 52, in generate_pyx_code_stage
    module_node.process_implementation(options, result)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\ModuleNode.py", line 143, in process_implementation
    self.generate_c_code(env, options, result)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\ModuleNode.py", line 385, in generate_c_code
    self.body.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py", line 442, in generate_function_definitions
    stat.generate_function_definitions(env, code)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py", line 3176, in generate_function_definitions
    FuncDefNode.generate_function_definitions(self, env, code)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Nodes.py", line 1974, in generate_function_definitions
    Buffer.put_acquire_arg_buffer(entry, code, self.pos)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Buffer.py", line 322, in put_acquire_arg_buffer
    getbuffer = get_getbuffer_call(code, entry.cname, buffer_aux, entry.type)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Buffer.py", line 345, in get_getbuffer_call
    dtype_typeinfo = get_type_information_cname(code, buffer_type.dtype)
  File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Buffer.py", line 684, in get_type_information_cname
    assert False
AssertionError
```

I think it'd be cool to get someones input on this, especially considering using basic types, like list[double], does not throw this same error mid-cython (but will throw a syntax error in a .py run).

Here's the small code used to recreate this:

---

```
#example.pyx
import typing
from typing import List

from libcpp.string cimport string
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "src/example.hpp":
    cdef void print_hello(vector[string] c_names)

def do_nothing() -> None:
    print("doing nothing")
    return

def py_print_hello(list[string] names_to_pass) -> None:
    return
```

---

```
//example.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "example.hpp"

using namespace std;

void print_hello(vector<string> c_names){
    cout << "Hello " << c_names.at(0) << " and " << c_names.at(1) << "!" << endl;
    return;
}
```

---

```
// example.hpp
#ifndef USING_EXAMPLE
#define USING_EXAMPLE

void print_hello(std::vector<std::string> c_names);

#endif
```

---

```
# setup.py
# x64 machine, C++11, Python 3.8

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize


#if you don't keep the source in a different folder compilation inplace overwrites
ext = Extension("pyexample",
                sources=["example.pyx", "src/example.cpp"],
                extra_compile_args=['-std=c++11'],
                language="c++")

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(ext, language_level = "3"))
```

---

Comment: Seems like a bug in cython to me, you shouldn't be hitting internal asserts at runtime like this.